# How can I get $params into my own scheduled job?

Tags: extension, developer, scheduled-job

Looking for some help on getting $params to be passed on from the scheduled job -> GUI page -> into my scheduled job; so:

```
function civicrm_api3_job_ecocalculate($params) {
```

I'd like to be able to pass in e.g.

[image]

But when I try this I just get `$params = null` in my function;

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I have:
[image]

(I know you can read it :-)

And in my code:

```
function civicrm_api3_note_Migrate($params) {
  // param migrate_type determines what will be selected, defaulted to contact
  $validTypes = array('contact', 'contribution', 'participant', 'relationship');
  if (!isset($params['migrate_type'])) {
    $entityTable = 'civicrm_contact';
  } else {
    if (in_array($params['migrate_type'], $validTypes)) {
      $entityTable = 'civicrm_'.$params['migrate_type'];
    } else {
      $entityTable = 'civicrm_contact';
    }
  }
}
```

But I am not sure if that is what you mean?

Comment: Why does this work for you and not for me? Niet eerlijk!

Comment: Ah - is working now! Perhaps I had my jobs mixed up; In any case - helemaal goed;